# How to check condition before executing MYSQL query (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, laravel-5

I wanna check if empty `$i` or `$search`

I got error message

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string
```

When i used this function

```
static function getListUserGroup($id = "", $search = "", $paginate = NULL)
{
    $sql = "";
    if (!empty($id))
    {
        $sql.= "->where('id', {$id})";
    }

    if (!empty($search))
    {
        $sql.= "->where('name', 'LIKE', {$search})";
    }

    if (!is_null($paginate) && !empty($paginate))
    {
        $sql.= "->paginate({$paginate})";
    }

    $results =  DB::table('core_user_roles').$sql;

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't just turn Laravel's database functions into strings and expect it to work like that. Laravel's `DB` and Eloquent functions are chainable, so you'd do it like this:.

```
static function getListUserGroup($id = "", $search = "", $paginate = NULL)
{
    $query = DB::table('core_user_roles');

    if($id) {
        // a slightly cooler syntax for simple wheres
        $query->whereId($id);
    }

    if($search) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $search);
    }

    if($paginate) {
        $query->paginate($paginate);
    }

    return $query;
}
```